# Why I cannot split big text file into smaller ones with line count in Python 2.6.6 after compile?

Tags: python, linux, split, command

I am trying to use the split command on Linux ( CentOS 6.7 ) within Python 2.6.6 to split a big text file ( a few Mb ) into many smaller ones by separating the big file with 10000 lines per file.

If I do this with the code I wrote directly executing the python script from source file it works BUT when I compile it with pyinstaller I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 38, in 
>   TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Python 2.6.6
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from os import path, system
from subprocess import call
from time import sleep
from sys import exit

def main():
    if ( path.exists('.Finaltmp') and path.isdir('.Finaltmp') ):
        Finalpath = '.Finaltmppath/'
    else:
        Finalpath = '.Finaltmp/'
    try:
        system('split -l 10000 /home/BIGfile.txt /home/.Finaltmp/')
        print(' \n Data Successfully Separated \n ')
        sleep(1)
    except:
        print(' \n .Finaltmp/ Directory does not exist... Terminating... \n ')
        exit(0)
    else:
        print(' \n ')
        sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It doesn't appear there are 38 lines in your program. Can you copy and paste the complete traceback

Comment: Why are you using a system call? a few mb is not exactly what I would call large, this can all be done very easily using just python

Comment: I just run it again. 
I forgot to mention that I am calling it from another python script and it gives me an error that says :

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                        
  File "main.py", line 38, in <module>                                           
    BIGfile()                                                                         
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

I call it the same way I call the others and the other scripts work except this one!

Comment: Guys I found it... omg.. OK so in the main.py I have all calls as Function.main() but on this Function I forgot .main().... epic fail.

Sorry to waste your time guys and thank you all for jumping in so fast to help out. I finally got it working!

You also mentioned that this can be done with python and not using call ... can you give me an example if possible ?

Thank you in advance.